# How to get the data from HTML field to the view.py in django(HTML field is iterating)

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have an app which reads the questions from database and display them .I need to enter the response to it and save it back in the database.Is it possible to do it without using forms
My HTML section

```
<form id="survey" method="post" action="/Survey/restricted/"  class="form col-md-12 center-block">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for b in obj1 %}
 <textarea class="form-control">{{b.question}}</textarea>
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="response1"   width="100%;">{{b.response}}</textarea>
{% endfor %}

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Response" />
</form>
```

I tried to access the data after entering the response and submitting using

```
res=request.POST.get('response1')
```

but it returns none

Comment: the form is populated with many fields all called `response1`

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `response1` field outside the loop, but then it should be passed as a separate field (e.g. `response`), not as part of the `obj1` list of questions (or not passed at all if keeping the previous answer is unnecessary).

```
<form id="survey" method="post" action="/Survey/restricted/"  class="form col-md-12 center-block">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for b in obj1 %}
 <textarea class="form-control">{{b.question}}</textarea>
{% endfor %}
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="response1"   width="100%;">{{response}}</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Response" />
</form>
```

Also, I think the questions should not be editable (i.e. disabled, or not a `textarea` altogether)

Comment: i need a text area(response) for each question .Is it possible and able to access those fields